# Avoid to create sessions on ping test

Tags: session, azure, web, ping

Currently, I'm working in a website deployed in microsoft azure. I saw an option where I can test the site availabilty using pings. I naively created that test and one week later I got a huge amount of sessions and users recorded.

I would like to know if there is a way to test the site availability without creating a session on every ping request.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The "Always On" feature of an Azure web site regularly pings your website to ensure availability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure Monitoring you define an URL which gets pinged to ensure site / application availability.

You can create a dedicated HttpHandler, or MVC Action that responds to that Monitoring endpoint. Your handler or action does not need to create Session (HttpHandler by default do not create and cannot access session). This handler can even perform some application checks to provide your application is alive and return respective response code.

In short: you are in full control of what URL is being called by monitoring as well as what you do with your Application at that URL.